# Div Position tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Senario is i have a div name scrollContent now another div is content which is inside scrollContent div and is scrollable. In Content div there are other div i want to track the position of all div in content div so that when i reopen the div inside content div open at same position. Here i want to track the position of div with id="p0" .
I am saving  content div height and width with 
    $('#content').prop('scrollHeight')
    $('#content').prop('scrollWidth')

when i reopen i assign the save height and width to content div. But div inside content div are not open at exact postion. I save the div position inside content div like this
    top=$("#p0").offset().top;
    left=$("#p0").offset().left;

Please suggest me . Thanks in advance

My Code is as below

```
<div id="scrollContent">
<div id="content">
<div id="p0" class="window ui-draggable" position="absolute" style="top:256px;left:132px;"/>
</div>
</div>

Css are
#scrollContent {
    border:inset 3px #EFF3FB;
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative;
    min-height:836px;
    min-width:400px;
    height:850px;
    width:1020px;

    left: 250px;
    right: 0;
    top: 15px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    background-color:#EFF3FB;
}
#content {
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative;
    min-height:836px;
    min-width:400px;
    height:836px;
    width:1000px;

    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-image:url('../image/new_background_content.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-image-width:100%;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$("#p0").offset().top - $("#content").offset().top;`

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SgCvc/)**

Comment: Hi vivek ... Am using this to save the style attribute of po but problem comes when the content div scroll . if content div doesnot scroll .. inside div are at exact position . But when content div scroll . all inside div open in same window not in scrolling part .

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle example and recreate the issue?